# I have 2 POJO's college and stream. College has a Set of stream. How to make correct json corresponding to Pojo in this case?

Tags: javascript, java, json, spring-restcontroller

I am trying to populate a POJO with the json data coming from frontend ajax call. But this was easy in case of POJO having simple fields. Now I have to modify my POJO class Student by including a Set streams in it. How will be the JSON data that I send from browser ? following is my code.

This is my javascript:

```
<script>

$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url : 'api/colleges',
    data :  JSON.stringify (
                 {
              collegeName : $("#name").val(),
              email : $("#email").val()
                 }),
    success: function(){
                    console.log("Values gone to database successfully!!");
                $("#regForm").hide();
            $("#addCollege").show();
            alert("Registeration Successful!");                     
           },
    error : function() {
         alert("Error");
             console.log("Oops an Error Occured!!!!")
                 }
    });

</script>
```

This is my new POJO having a Set of another POJO class stream:

```
public class College {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="college_name")
    private String collegeName;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="college")
    private Set<Stream> streams;
}
```

This is the POJO Stream:

```
public class Stream {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="stream_name")
    private String streamName;

    @Column(name="stream_intake")
    private int streamIntake;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id", nullable=false)
    private College college;
}
```

Comment: JSON does not support sets. One possible way to circumvent this would be to use a `List` for serialization/deserialization, and transform that into a `Set` when working with it in your application. The downside of this is that it implies an ordering to your clients that will not be preserved.

Comment: my main focus here is not just to use a SET I can easily replace my Set in Java POJO and use a LIST instead. Imagine if it was a list and in that scenario how would the JSON look like ? As my main focus is to create JSON to resemble my JAVA POJO so that i can use @RequestBody annotation to directly put json data into my pojo class

Comment: In that case, see Julien's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Edit : change number of colleges

What you could do is design an example of your json, something like this (roughly done):

```
[
 {
  "id": 28,
  "college_name": "Harvard",
  "email" : "email@harvard.com",
  "college": [
   {
    "id": 42,
    "stream_name":"STREAM_1",
    "stream_intake": 456
   },
   {
    "id": 23,
    "stream_name":"STREAM_2",
    "stream_intake": 342
   },
   {
    "id": 21,
    "stream_name":"STREAM_30",
    "stream_intake": 567
   }
  ] 
 },
 {
  "id": 29,
  "college_name": "Cambridge",
  "email" : "email@cambridge.com",
  "college": [
   {
    "id": 42,
    "stream_name":"STREAM_1",
    "stream_intake": 456
   },
   {
    "id": 45,
    "stream_name":"STREAM_3",
    "stream_intake": 452
   }
  ] 
 }
]
```

and then use a tool like this on to get your pojo :
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
be sure to choose **JSON** as a **Source type** and then play with options and download your Java classes.

Comment: This approach is correct i thought of the same. But the number of streams objects given to key "college" is fixed in your example i.e for college_name: "Harvard" .....you have 2 stream objects  STREAM_1 and STREAM_2 in an array. What if number of streams are decided by the user and if its dynamic instead of hardcoding it to just 2 streams in one array. ? This is what i exactly want to achieve please help me out .

Comment: in this json the number of college is not fixed as it is in an array [ ], I put 2 but you can have 0 or as many as you want.. I edited the post to change the number of college in the first...

Comment: But here the question is I as a developer I dont know how many streams a user will provide. If user provides 50 streams !! then how will i place 50 objects in that array which i made of just 2 objects or 3 objects ??? I want this to happen dynamically that an array size should be evaluated only after user provides how many streams are there in his/her college

Comment: Basically I want to loop it . That means for every iteration a new object must get added to "college" = [ ]  . And the loop must run only for number of times equal to  no of streams that user has already provided in an input text box.

Comment: ok, look at this simple example : https://js.do/code/281397 I don't know the content of your textarea, so I simplified the stuff.